# create a stored procedure within SAS

Tags: sas

I have 100 insert statements like these ones

```
INSERT INTO table_A (col1,col2col3) VALUES ('ab','jerry',123); 

INSERT INTO table_A (col1,col2col3) SELECT col1,col2,col3 FROM Test WHERE col1='ab';

INSERT INTO table_B (col1,col2col3) SELECT loc1,loc2,loc3 FROM Test_v2 WHERE loc2='ab';
```

I'm running the queries every 2 months. The `WHERE` clauses are not changing and the recipient table is being deleted every 2 months too, making it clean slate.

I've been looking the internet but it does not seem possible to create the equivalent of a SQL stored procedure and be able to run it , once it in a while .

Or is it ...?

If it doesn't exist, I'm willing to rewrite it but I want to make sure that it does not exist before doing so.

TIA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends on your setup.  If you have a SAS Server (including a metadata server), you can create stored processes, which is a direct analogue.  See [this paper](http://support.sas.com/rnd/itech/doc9/dev_guide/stprocess/program.html) or the documentation.

If your main concern is repeatability, you should just use a macro.  If, on the other hand, you're interested in scheduling, you have two major options.

First, a `.sas` program can be scheduled in batch mode very easily; see [Batch processing under Windows](http://www.sascommunity.org/wiki/Batch_processing_under_Windows) or look for a similar article for your operating system of choice.  This entails simply setting up a `.bat` program that will execute your `.sas` program, and then asking the Windows scheduler to run it however often you need.

Second, an Enterprise Guide process flow can be scheduled via a handy tool built into the program.  Go to File -> Schedule , or right click on a process flow and select Schedule .  This will create a `.vbs` and register it with the Windows scheduler.

Comment: Hi Joe, happy new year. I'll have a look at macro as you have advised. Thanks.